# Definition of variance for discrete random variables

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory

In some books when variance of a discrete random variable is introduced it is mentioned that $\mathbb E[(X-\mathbb E X)^2]$ must exists (converge) so we can talk about the variance.

In some other books when variance is introduced it is only mentioned that $\mathbb E[X^2]$ must exist for the variance to exist. I am wondering why $\mathbb E[X^2]$ is enough for the variance to exist.

**My thoughts**

$Var(X)=\mathbb E(X^2) - [\mathbb E(X)]^2$, so for "$\mathbb E[X^2]$ exists" to be a sufficient condition we need to show that from "$\mathbb E[X^2]$ exists" follows "$\mathbb E[X]$ exists", but I am not sure how to show it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inequality:$$\left|X\right|\leq1+X^{2}$$ implies that $\mathbb E\left|X\right|<\infty$ if $\mathbb EX^2<\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

By Hölder's inequality,
$$
\mathbb{E}|X|^r\le\bigl(\mathbb{E}|X|^s\bigr)^{r/s}
$$
for $0<r<s$. Hence, if $\mathbb{E}|X|^s<\infty$, then $\mathbb{E}|X|^r<\infty$. If $s=2$ and $r=1$, then the same inequality can be obtained using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.